# Unable to get csv link from the WebPage

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I endeavored scraping a webpage to extract the csv link. I used selenium webdriver to get the Page source which can be used by bs4.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriver_Path, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.apple.com/covid19/mobility")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
Link = soup.select('#download-card > div.download-button-container > a')[0].text
```

when i print(Link) it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with BeautifulSoup because it doesn't support javascript. And that specific page is built mostly with javascript.

You could use selenium instead. Something like:

```
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
>>> driver.find_element(By.ID,'download-card').find_element_by_class_name('download-button-container').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[0].get_attribute('href')
'https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2014HotfixDev17/v3/en-us/applemobilitytrends-2020-08-16.csv'
```

You can probably make it prettier. This was just quick & dirty.